# Detect if running from middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to detect if my code is running from a Middleware. I have a helper that get's called from everywhere for date conversions. In that helper, I check for route names  `\Route::current()->getName()` or if running from console `\App::runningInConsole()`.

When my middleware calls the helper, I get an error with `\Route::current()->getName()` since `\Route::current()` is `null`

Is there a way of knowing if code executed from my middleware?
Thanks

**Problem solved**

I had problems integrating Cashier and middleware and got that fixed, and to prevent going to my timezonehelper to set dates, I used the `protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'ends_at'];`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you do that? I would probably pass an argument to the helper to detect the running mode (Console or HTTP).

Comment: I have lots of different conditions in my helper that check `\Route::current()->getName()` , and when the middleware gets to the helper, there's no current route, `\Route::current()` is null so I get errors with `\Route::current()->getName()`. I could add conditions to check if calling from middleware

Comment: This actually says you are not having the best design for your code. Still I recommend to pass parameter for this helper to identify the mode you want to use, even they are several scenarios, make that parameter an int parameter that can have any value.

Comment: Your code is ought to break with any Laravel release, you are tightly coupling it to the Framework, so with any update you will have more code to change.

Comment: Yes, I know I do not have the best design in my get timezone helper, mix of conditions are: Auth or not, specific routes, running from console, so those conditions need to be checked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get full url in laravel using the code below
$fullUrl = Request::capture()->fullUrl();

And You can get current url in laravel using the code below
        $currentUrl = Routes::current()->getName();

In this case, you have to use this namespace given below:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route as Routes;